# How to prevent gethostid from doing DNS lookups on linux

Tags: linux, dns

Our application (RHEL 5/c++) uses the hostid as returned by `gethostid` for logging purposes. For some reason, the primary DNS server of the local network environment went offline. This resulted in  massive problems in `gethostid`: The function call hangs for more than 60s, which lead to internal timeouts in our application. A call to `hostid` on the commandline also didn't return after several minutes. Once the DNS server was up again, the timeouts/problems both in the application and the `hostid` commandline tool disappeared.

My question is: How do I prevent `gethostid` from making DNS lookups? There`re some boundary conditions to the answer:

- The file `/etc/hostid` must not exist.
- Calling `sethostid` is not allowed.
- Changing `/etc/hosts` is not possible.

I'm astonished this happens at all. As I understand `gethostid` it works like this:

1. Return the value of the last `sethostid` if it has been set manually.
2. Return hostid form /etc/hostid if the file exists.
3. Return the primary IP of the host if set.
4. Fail for other cases.

I don`t see the need for a DNS query.

To verify, that `gethostid` actually is dependend on a working DNS server, try this:

- As root create/change your /etc/reslov.conf so it contains only invalid `nameserver` entries.
- Call `hostid` on the commandline.

On my debian/squeeze installation this results in a hostid of `00000000` without any hangs. I assume the RedHat-version of `hostid` is different/older and results hangs.

Comment: Some small details I forgot: `/etc/nsswitch.conf` contains `hosts: files dns`. The hostname of the primary IP of the system is not in `/etc/hosts`. This is by desing and a customer requirement.

Comment: Is just removing `dns` from `/etc/nsswitch.conf` an acceptable solution?

Comment: I don't think so. This would prevent all DNS lookups, right? Definitively an undesired side effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think preventing DNS lookups from `gethostid` is not really possible without breaking the system or violating one of the boundary conditions. On [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Host-Identification.html) I've found this comment on the `sethostid` function:

> The proper way to establish the primary IP address of a system is to configure the IP address resolver to associate that IP address with the system's host name as returned by gethostname. For example, put a record for the system in /etc/hosts.

From this I conclude, that `gethostid` determines the IP like this:

- Get the hostname from `gethostname`.
- Determine the IP via `gethostbyname` (or a similar method).

Under the conditions, that the host name is not associated to an IP address in `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf` allows DNS lookups,  a DNS lookup will be made by `gethostid`.